Flask Migrate always create/ set varchar size to Max
I do migrate in Flask.
This is my class:
    class DocumentBc23(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        packing_list_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('packing_list.id'), nullable=False)
        nomorAju = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
        kodeDokumen = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
        kodeKantor = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
        kodeKantorBongkar = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
        kodeTujuanTpb = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
        kodeTutupPu = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
        nomorBc11 = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
        tanggalBc11 = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)

This is the result in SQL Server:
Varchar always max
It wasn't like this before. The program once moved from the old server to the new server. I'm suspicious because of this. But I don't understand about installation and things regarding this.
Is there anything that needs to be set first so that the size doesn't become Max?

Do you know the size of each column that you want? I don't know how the system could have ever inferred anything else otherwise. What length should it pick for kodeDokumen, for example? You can say db.Column(db.String(50)) in cases where you know you need a varchar(50), no?

@AaronBertrand OH MAN! I am so dumb. I make this with excel. I think i choose wrong cell. I'll delete this dumb question later. Just want to say Thank you to you
